# Label not updating in statusstrip with progressbar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have been developing a windows forms application in vc# express 2013. I have a statusstrip control where i have a label and a progress bar. I want to show the progress of progressbar in label but it is not updating with the progress bar value. it only gets updated when the progress bar is complete i.e. when value is 100 and the job is finished. The strange thing is that the progress bar is updated but the label is not... Any ideas what might be happening here? By the way, I raise a progress event in my own code which is handled and the progress is updated accordingly...
Thanks

I raise the event ProgressTick in MGFDataHandler Class

```
if ((hundredthValue*progressMultiplier == lineCounter) || (lineCounter==totalLines))
            {
                //Raise the progress bar event!
                EventHandler handler = ProgressTick;                                        
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, e);
                }
                progressMultiplier++;
            }
```

I then handle it in windowsform as follows:

```
void msDataHandler_ProgressTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progress = (int)((MGFDataHandler)sender).progressMultiplier;            
        if (progress < 100)
        {
            this.progressStatusString.Text = "Progress: " + progress + "%";                
            this.progressBar.Visible = true;
            this.progressBar.Value = progress;
        }            
        else 
        {
            this.progressStatusString.Text = "Done";
            this.filterMSDataToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;                
        }
    }
```

The function which starts the whole thing is in the windowsform_activated event and MGFDataHandler object is an attribute of the windowsform.

```
private void GlycoMSPipelineMainFrame_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (this.whoActivatedMe)
        {
            case WhoActivatedMe.MSFilterWizard:
                {
                    this.whoActivatedMe = WhoActivatedMe.Me;
                    foreach (String currentmgffilename in this.currentMGFFileNames)
                    {
                        mgfDataHandler.Filter_MS_Data(currentmgffilename);
                    }                        
                    this.populateTreeViews();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

It is the Filter_MS_Data that raises the event.

Comment: show us some code, and some more information please

Comment: I left you an answer. Does it help? do you need any further information?

Answer (score 0):

I do need some more information for a full answer, but the direction in which this is heading to is quite clear to me.

The problem is that you're probably doing everything in the same thread. When you have a big job you need to use a background thread to do the work, and let the main thread (i.e. a UI thread) handle the UI.

This is a big topic and I'm just scratching the surface here, so first of all read the following links and try to create a thread for your job and invoke the update of the progress bar yourself. If not successful, then post a new question with more information.

The links you should read are:

- [Threads in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [ProgressBar in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)

Comment: You just took part of my answer and elaborated on it! Bah

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am indeed doing the whole thing in one thread and I suspected that this might be happening but then the question is how come the progressbar.value is able to update the GUI and not the label.text? Its been a while since I did multithreading professionally... but will give it a try if you guys are sure that is the issue here...

Comment: @waqas well, i'll have to see more information for answering the label.text update. but it's probably some update to the wrong text or something of the sort

Comment: @Ninja_Noob i understand that you are new to SO and it might take a while to learn how to answer a question the right way. i actually didn't read your answer until this comment. yes, the main idea is to use multithreading, but that doesn't mean i "took" part of your answer. that only mean that both of us thought the same thing. but the different is how to make this thinking into a solid easy-to-understand answer. enjoy SO

Comment: Haha sorry I was only joking about stealing my answer. I guess that didn't translate well in text form. As for answering more completely... I've learnt today so I've improved my answer. Thank you though I am grateful for your feedback. You've helped me to grow and improve a skill! I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a background worker  (found in System.componentModel) to run the task that you are performing. When updating the label or progress back you will need to check if invoke is required.

Something like this.

```
If (label.InvokeRequired) { 
label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
 { 
label.Text = progress.Value;
 });
}
```

Invoke is required to prevent cross threading operations which in turn can produce race conditions.

Forgive the formatting i typed this out on my phone.

You will need to perform the population using a background worker. I think this will resolve your issue.

Edit:
The background worker provides a do work event which will run on another thread. It also provides a finished event so you know when the task is complete.

I think what is happening here is that your program is performing work on the ui thread which prevents the ui from fully updating.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but i found it with the same issue in VS2019.  I found that rather than adding a thread, you can call the Refresh method of the container of the label and ProgressBar.

```
void msDataHandler_ProgressTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progress = (int)((MGFDataHandler)sender).progressMultiplier;            
        if (progress < 100)
        {
            this.progressStatusString.Text = "Progress: " + progress + "%";                
            this.progressBar.Visible = true;
            this.progressBar.Value = progress;
        }            
        else 
        {
            this.progressStatusString.Text = "Done";
            this.filterMSDataToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;                
        }
        this.progressStatusString.Owner.Refresh();
    }
```